# Getting incorrect date in "updated" column in indexer grid

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento2.4.6

Getting incorrect date in "updated" column in indexer grid after upgrading magento 246p1

[image]

And in the indexer_state table updated column shows 0000-00-00
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue, we need to execute ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY SQL queries to corrupted columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `mview_state` MODIFY `updated` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT 'View updated time';
ALTER TABLE `indexer_state` MODIFY `updated` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT 'Indexer Status';
```